# dynamic css style not working on ie?

Tags: angularjs, styles

I have a simple problem of dynamic css setting not working on ie properly:

I have this code:

```
 <div class="i-storage-bar-chart-bar-container">
                <div class="i-storage-bar-chart-bar"
                     style="height: {{(storage.totalStorage * 100) / model.maxStorageCapacity}}%">
                    <div class="i-storage-bar-chart-bar-inner"
                         style="height: {{(storage.usedStorage * 100) / storage.totalStorage}}%"></div>
                </div>
```

This kind of code does a simple chart with height of what i told it inside the curly braces, this is working ok in chrome and firefox, but in ie it doesn't do anything, only way to get it working is by doing the following: (non dynamic)

```
 <div class="i-storage-bar-chart-bar-container">
                <div class="i-storage-bar-chart-bar"
                     style="height: 20%">
                    <div class="i-storage-bar-chart-bar-inner"
                         style="height:10%"></div>
                </div>
```

What can i do to fix this problem for ie and still maintaining the dynamic stuff happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

on your controller:

```
$scope.style = { 'height': (storage.totalStorage * 100 / model.maxStorageCapacity) + '%' }
```

and on your div:

```
<div ng-style="style"></div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's in ng-repeat in the view, there is no way to do it only on the view side of things?

Comment: I don't like the entire design, inDOM calculation and inDOM json build, do both on the controller for each element in you repeated array and just assign the style variable of each element